# BXslider and making call for active LI on onAfterSlide callback

Tags: jquery, slider, bxslider

Working on a slider built off of bxslider.js

I require a callback that sets the LI to active on slide and removes the active class off the previous LI that it was just on.

I've gotten a very crude example working but lack the JS knowledge to write a script that detects onAfterSlide the active slide, tells the corresponding LI to be active and then removes any active state from any previous LI. The onlcick callback is working just fine, the onAfterSlide needs some love.

Somewhat working example: http://diveidc.com/slider.php
Here I have really crude attempt to get the next LI to become active but can't remove the previous LI active. The basically go all red since they all get assign the active class, as the slide goes through it's loop I need to only assign the active class to the LI that corresponds to the current slide. ie: slide1=li1 active, slide2=li2 active etc.

Source of the BXslider http://bxslider.com/options

Answer (score 0):

```
onAfterSlide: function(active) {
   $('someul li').each(function() {
      if($(this).index() == active)
         $(this).addClass('active');
   });
}
```

I haven't tested this, so use on your own risk :)